# Unexpected token found but dont see it

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I got this in my console

```html
index.php?usermsg=Testing+new+login&submitmsg=Send:69 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Im not quite sure what this means since i couldnt find anything that didnt belong

```c#
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("server/send.php", {text: clientmsg, server: current_server, username: current_user});               
        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
        return false;
    });
```

The html code

```html
<form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Share HTML code or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ele updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behavior of `input -> submit`

```
$("#submitmsg").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

---

```
$("#submitmsg").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
  $.post("server/send.php", {
    text: clientmsg,
    server: current_server,
    username: current_user
  });
  $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
  return false;
});
```